# extracting data from specific lines in a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

EDIT: Sorry, bad wording.

What I have is a text file with various lines, I want know how to specify a line on which to use re.sub. SO for example if I want part of line 3, how do I point re.sub at the content of line 3.

to give more background. The file has data on each line like line 0 = title line, line 1 = total reads, line 2 = % reads. I am to assign numbers from these lines to variables for use later.

extracting data from specific lines in a text file. Using the below code....

```
for i, line in enumerate(textfile):
       print i, line
```

gives me the output

```
0 line printed here
1 line printed here
```

planning to use `re.sub()` to get the part of the line I want. But how do I refer to the specific line/text. Was thinking something like..

```
target = ""

for i, line in enumerate(textfile):
       if i == 1:
           target = re.sub(r"line (printed) here", r"\1", line)
```

but thats not quite right

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: what exactly do you want? Are you wanting to extract data only matching a certain line number?

Comment: If you're using `enumerate`, remember that like most counting things in Python, it starts at 0. "Zero based indexing." For things like lines in a file that have a 1-based convention (i.e. first line called "line 1" not "line 0"), you can set the start index like this: `enumerate(textfile, start=1)`

Comment: Hi Guys, read edit. I understand re.sub and enumerate. What i need to know is how to point re.sub at the line I want data from

Comment: You are looking for the pattern `line (printed) here` and then replacing with `\1` in the `line`. But file has the following content `line printed here` in the first line. I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: how the expected output would look like? did you want to print the second column only from particular lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am getting you right, you are looking to extract data from selective lines only, say, `(1, 4, 5, 9)`.

In that case, do:

```
for i, line in enumerate(textfile):
    if i in (1, 4, 5, 9):
        target = re.sub(r"line (printed) here", r"\1", line)
```

Note that enumerate will start with index 0, so the first line of the file will correspond to index 0, 2nd line of the file for index 1, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is simply how to use your `re.sub()` on a particular line, you could use something like you have *(for the lines you want of course)*. Perhaps your error is you forgot to open your file.

```
myfile = open("textfile")

    for i, line in enumerate(myfile):
        if i == 1:
            # this is your second line
            target = re.sub(r"line (printed) here", r"\1", line) 
        elif i == 6:
            # this is your seventh line

        elif i > 100:
            break

    myfile.close()
```